# Adding two colors as background without using gradient

Tags: android, android-xml, android-shape

I was trying to apply shadow effect for my views and find out that I could use gradient to do it.

I created an XML file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <gradient 
        android:endColor="@android:color/transparent"
        android:centerColor="@android:color/transparent"
        android:startColor="@android:color/black"
        android:angle="135"/>
</shape>
```

This works fine, but I needed to make it more like a shadow.
What I need is to remove the transition effect in gradient because I only need two colors in one view applied diagonally. How to do it?[image]

Comment: Why don't you use two Layouts instead of one and so you apply a color on each of it without using any shape. It's easier

Comment: Could you attach an image with expected shadow?

Comment: @vokilam added the image

Comment: if you need such a background Drawable,  you cannot use xml Drawable for that,  the easiest is to write a custom Drawable and overwrite its draw() method

Answer (score 0):

If you want that to be something like tha background of your views, why don't you just save a B/W `.jpeg` or `.png` image inside your `Drawables` and use it when needed specifying its dimensions and `alpha` (opacity) parameter?

Answer (score 0):

In that case I'd suggest using nine-patch drawables